# Iterate over a list of images and assign them as variables in python

Tags: python, image, iteration, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a function that iterates over a list of images in python so that they are accessible for Pillow image processing.

```
ImTestA = Image.open("A.png")
ImTestB = Image.open("B.png")
ImTestC = Image.open("C.png")
ImTest1 = Image.open("1.png")
ImTest2 = Image.open("2.png")
ImTest3 = Image.open("3.png")
ImTest4 = Image.open("4.png")
ImTest5 = Image.open("5.png")
ImTest6 = Image.open("6.png")
```

I currently have the above but am trying to refactor it into something I can assign different length to (use a list with A-K or J-Z).

```
from PIL import Image

AtoC = ["A.png", "B.png", "C.png"]

def OpenAns(quest):
    AtoCImages = []
    for image in quest:
        AtoCImages.append(Image.open(image))
        return AtoCImages

OpenAns(AtoC)

ImTestA = AtoCImages[0]
ImTestB = AtoCImages[1]
ImTestC = AtoCImages[2]
```

Fixed earlier error, and went back to same problem as before. I am just trying to clean up my code and have it nice and DRY. Any help is appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ImageTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    ImTestA = AtoCImages[0]
NameError: name 'AtoCImages' is not defined
```

Maybe I will just have separate files with a list in each. If I cant shorten this up.

Comment: Yep.  You are overwriting `AtoCIm` at the beginning of each iteration with `AtoCIm = []`.  Move it outside loop.

Answer (score 7):

Change:

```
for image in AtoC:
    AtoCIm = []
    AtoCIm.append(Image.open(image))
```

to

```
AtoCIm = []
for image in AtoC:
    AtoCIm.append(Image.open(image))
```

will do it.

You are creating a new list every iteration, rather than creating a list once and appending new items to it. Therefore, your list always has only 1 item. Attempting to get the 2nd item, `AtoCIm[1]`, will raise exception.

Comment: looks like a course assignment..., hey, we all drink and code, only difference being what we drink

Answer (score 1):

`AToCImages` is a list you created within `OpenAns()` function, hence it is a local variable for that function. Local variables can't be accessed beyond their scope (in this case the `OpenAns()` function) and are only defined within it. Hence when you try to assign it outside the function,

```
ImTestA = AtoCImages[0]
ImTestB = AtoCImages[1]
ImTestC = AtoCImages[2]
```

it throws an error.